# Remove only pagenumbers from llncs

Tags: header-footer, lncs

How do you remove *only* the page number from the springer llncs template, leaving the rest of the header untouched ?

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}


\urldef{\mailsa}\path|mail}@camous.de|

\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\par\addvspace\baselineskip
\noindent\keywordname\enspace\ignorespaces#1}

\bibliographystyle{splncs03}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\title{title}
\titlerunning{titlerunning}
\toctitle{toctitle}

\author{author}
\authorrunning{authorrunning}
\tocauthor{tocauthor}

\institute{institute}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
content

\keywords{words}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
 content

\clearpage

core content

\end{document}
```

seems fairly simple but neither `\pagestyle{empty}` nor `\pagenumbering{gobble}` do the trick.

Comment: Do you plan to submit this to Springer? If yes, then please consider that the editors of that company will reject your manuscript because they intended to have the page numbers where they are

Comment: No, this is for a paper for the LWDA17, where they want "LNCS format without page numbers".

Comment: I see ..... I think, that the pagestyle must be changed

Comment: So one can now argue if "without page numbers" is the same as without header at all or not. But I'd like to take them literally if possible.

Comment: `\ps@headings` is the culprit. It should be changed

Comment: This was the needed hint thank you. You are a hero.

Comment: So instead of just fixing this once by the journal/conference staff, everybody submitting has to do the same labour? `Effectivity^{-1}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep the `runningheads` document class option, I suggest you add the following instructions to your document's preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for "\patchcmd" macro
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\rlap{\thepage}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\llap{\thepage}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings} % reload the now-modified "headings" page style
```

Alternatively, simply drop the `runningheads` option: The `llncs` document class will then set `\pagestyle{empty}` automatically -- no page numbers, and nothing else in the headers and footers...

Answer (score 0):

Within the `llncs.cls` file there is a line starting with `\ps@headings` (line 1183 and 1186). There one can delete the `\thepage` entry to remove the page numbers.

Comment: Well, do not change the `.cls` itself. There are other ways to correct such 'unwanted' features

Answer (score 0):

Just a small refinement on Mico's answer to take out the tabulation as well:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for "\patchcmd" macro
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\rlap{\thepage}\hspace{\headlineindent}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\hspace{\headlineindent}\llap{\thepage}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings} % reload the now-modified "headings" page style
```

Otherwise if for any reason etoolbox does not work, remove `\rlap{\thepage}\hspace{\headlineindent}` and `\hspace{\headlineindent} \llap{\thepage}` from the `\def\ps@headings` section in `llncs.cls`.